# Android - get index #0 , #1 , #2 of a number

Tags: java, android

how to get index #0 , #1 , #2 of a number

for example

> long sec = 8541; //get 541;
>
> long sec = 5276; //get 276;
>
> long sec = 463; //get 463;
>
> long sec = 95; //get 95;

and etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want the 3 first digits (from the right). You can get them by using modulo 1000 :

```
long sec = 12345;
long res = sec%1000; //res will be 345
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Modulo is your way to go and much more safer than the other answers. You don't have to pay attention to the numbers length.

Comment: I give you my vote, much elegant than my answer to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int digitAtPositionOne = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(sec).substring(0, 1)); //change this accordingly

int digitAtPositionTwo = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(sec).substring(0, 2)); //change this accordingly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subString from the wanted index to get only part of the number like this :

```
int yourNewNumber = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(sec).substring(start index, end index));
```

**Note** - if you won't fill your end index your new number will start at the start index given until the last index